# Can I update an expectation $\mathbb{E}[X | A, B, C]$ with a conditional probability $P(X | Y)$ without knowing anything about $A, B, C$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Can I update an expectation $\mathbb{E}[X | A, B, C]$ with a conditional probability $P(X | Y)$?

Hello everyone, I am tackling a problem where I have a conditional Expectation $\mathbb{E}[X | A, B, C]$,
for some unknown Random Variables $A, B, C, \dots$ and two known probabilities, $P(X)$ and $P(X | Y)$. Where $ Y \not\in {A, B, C, \dots}$.

Now I would like to use those two probabilities to update the expectation.
I thought about using multiplying $\mathbb{E}[X | A, B, C, \dots]$ ratio $\frac{P(X|Y = y)}{P(X)}$ but I am not quite sure how to interpret the new quantity.

Is it possible to get $\mathbb{E}[X | A, B, C, \dots, Y]$ with the new probabilities?
I've been trying but don't get there without knowing $A, B, C$ since the only way I can think of doing it would be Total Expectation.

Many thanks for any ideas and insights you can provide!

Comment: In general, if you have _random vectors_ $X, Y, Z$ such that $(X, Y)$ is independent of $Z,$ then $\mathbf{E}(X \mid Y, Z) = \mathbf{E}(X \mid Y).$ In other cases, not much can be said and I've seen counterexamples to different claims you could come up.

Comment: @WilliamM. thanks a lot! Yes, X is dependent on Y, its just that the expected value I have only uses other variables and I wanted to kind of "update" without distorting the meaning of the value.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying intuitively. Lucky for you, I don't need to to understand either as mathematically if you define $Z$ to be the _vector_ $(A, B, \ldots),$ and $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z,$ you will reach what you want.

Comment: oh, like a reparameterization @WilliamM. ? I will give this a try, thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: @WilliamM. It's been a while and I've been toying around but unfortunately I still don't understand how I could redefine. I tried doing parameterization but am not reaching the promiseland here. Would you mind elaborating what you mean with defining $Z$ as the random vector and letting the joint Distribution of $(X, Y)$ be independent of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two *events* $A_1, A_2$  are independent if we can write
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_2)
$$

Two *random variables* $X_1, X_2$  are independent if we can write
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1|X_2=x_2)\mathbb{P}(X_2=x_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1)\mathbb{P}(X_2=x_2)
$$
i.e. the joint probability as the product of the marginal probabilities. Intuitively, you can ignore the information on $X_2$ to know the probability of $X_1=x_1$.

For ease of exposition take the random variables $X,A,B,Y$ such that $Y$ is independent of $X,A,B$. This condition is the one interesting for you, according to your question and comments.

The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, Y = y]$, is:
$$
\sum_{x} xP(X = x | A = a,B = b, Y = y ) = \sum_{x} \frac{xP(X=x,A = a,B = b, Y = y)}{P(A = a,B = b, Y = y)}
$$

Because of the independence of $Y$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, Y = y]=\sum_{x} \frac{xP(X=x,A = a,B = b)}{P(A = a,B = b)}
$$
That is, since $Y$ is independent, you cannot have a value for $
\mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, Y = y]$ without information on $P(A = a,B = b)$.

Comment: I see thank you very much, do you think I misunderstood the other commenter there then?
Because I understood their remark as meaning that if I just set $Y$ as independent from the rest I could somehow figure it out, but I did come to the same conclusion as you above over and over again and thought I missed something.

Comment: Your other question completes this one. I have added an answer.  For those interested, the related question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607652/how-can-i-use-z-a-b-c-and-the-joint-x-y-to-find-exa-b-c-y-with?noredirect=1&lq=1. I also want to point out that I think your question is interesting as it helps us to see additional ones. For instance, what is independence? what are independent events? what are independent random variables? what is a random variable? what is a filtration?