# How can I use $Z = (A, B, C)$ and the joint $(X, Y) $to find $E[X|A,B,C,Y]$ without knowing anything about $A,B,C$?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

some time ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591953/can-i-update-an-expectation-mathbbex-a-b-c-with-a-conditional-probabi), someone kind has offered a tip in the comments, but I have been toying with it every other day for 20 minutes or so since and can't see how to use this trick.
How can I use $Z = (A, B, C)$ and the joint $(X, Y) $to find $E[X|A,B,C,Y]$ without knowing anything about $A,B,C$ besides the Expectation $E[X|A, B, C]$?

Why is it ok to set the joint independent of $Z$? It sounded a bit like the reparameterization logic to me, but is still a little different than how I know it.

Any tips and insights are greatly appreciated, I've spent quite a bit of time on trying to solve this.

Comment: It is not okay to assume independence. In general you cannot solve this problem exactly without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between this question and [the one you posted before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591953/can-i-update-an-expectation-mathbbex-a-b-c-with-a-conditional-probabi), is that in this one you explicity know the value of $\mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, C = c]$.

If $Y$ is independent of $A,B,C$, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, C = c, Y = y] = \mathbb{E}[X |A = a,B = b, C = c]$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and additional answer, I am happy that I can put this quest to rest now, even knowing that I won't get much further.